# Call JavaScript function from global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, global-asax, scriptmanager

I want to call the JavaScript function (which internally shows a popup about the error message) from global.asax.cs file. Here is my code that I am trying in Global.asax.cs file,

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.Page mypage = (System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    mypage.RegisterStartupScript("alert", "<script language=javascript>alert('test');</script>");
}
```

But it is not calling the alert nor giving any error or warning message in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) and the Google Chrome console. How can JavaScript code be called?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? This approach isn't going to work like you want it to.

Comment: i want to log any unhandled exception and show it in popup which is created by javascript function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different kind of errors that you get at that point.

1. Errors that are thrown by the compiler.
2. Errors that are thrown by your program.

**The compiler can throw any error there**, for example, it can not find a literal control in the code behind. In this case your page does not even exist and there is no way to get it at that point and give this JavaScript alert.

**Errors by the run time of your program**, for example, a null exception, can also stop the page from rendered and this is also stop the page and you can not have the page handler there.

So the `HttpContext.Current.Handler is NOT a page`.

In general, the Application_Error is used for capture and log `unhandled errors`, to solve them later, and maybe show a better error page to the user.

If you try just to see your error on debug, you can use code like:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception LastOneError = Server.GetLastError();
    if (LastOneError != null)
    {
        Debug.Fail("Unhandled error: " + LastOneError.ToString());
        LogTheError(LastOneError);
    }
}
```

### Custom error page

The only way that I can think to make something similar is to make a redirect when the error appears to a new page that explain the error - but this is what the custom error page already do.

### More

This is the way I handle my custom errors and stay on the same page. The file check is to avoid possible close loop that can crash the pool.

```
  string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

  if (!cTheFile.EndsWith("ErrorHandlePage.aspx"))
      Server.Transfer("~/ErrorHandlePage.aspx");
```

Comment: for that i will have to do redirect or server.transfer right ? any suggestion on how can i keep the user on the same page.

Comment: @Mehul9595 I do a Server.Transfer("~/PageNotFound.aspx"); and inside the PageNotFound.aspx I show my custom errors. (attention to avoid loop redirect at that point ! eg PageNotFound throw again error ! This crash the pool)

Comment: i guess this will also change the page that i am currently seeing

Comment: @mehul9595 Yes of course. The page that throw the exception is unable to render any more. If you like to keep the page, take care the errors and the messages with try{}catch{} in the code behind on your code.

Answer (score 2):

This writes to the page and pops up a message box.  I put it in a global.asax.cs file (code behind).  Tested with a divide by zero error:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String ErrorStr = "Application_Error " + Server.GetLastError().Message;

    Response.Write("<h2>Global Page Error</h2>\n");
    Response.Write("<p>" + ErrorStr + "</p>\n");

    Response.Write("<Script Language='javascript'> alert('Hello');</script>");

    // Clear the error from the server
    Server.ClearError();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is you can't.

There is no page in Global.asax so no context in which run javascript.

Comment: but using this (System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler i should be able to get current page context.

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't work like you're expecting.  You are not able to run javascript from the global.asax file.  If you give us some more information into what you are doing maybe we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN page *[Page.RegisterStartupScript Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)* has an example of what you are trying to do.

I think your problem is that when you are registering the script with that page, it's too late. The life cycle of the page object is over, and it's not going to render anything additional data to the page.